# How to prevent customer from change DOB?

Tags: magento-1, customer-account

We want to use a function that will give customers free points when their birthday? But how to prevent customers to change DOB now and then to get extra birthday points?

Answer (score 2):

You may solve your problem in a few ways.

1. You may edit `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/customer/widget/dob.phtml` add check is customer entered his DOB.

Change:

```
<?php
    $this->setDateInput('d',
        '<div class="dob-day">
             <input '.  .' type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('day') . '" value="' . $this->getDay() . '" title="' . $this->__('Day') . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams() . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '">' . $this->__('DD') . '</label>
         </div>'
    );

    $this->setDateInput('m',
        '<div class="dob-month">
             <input type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('month') . '" value="' . $this->getMonth()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Month')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '">' . $this->__('MM')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );

    $this->setDateInput('y',
        '<div class="dob-year">
             <input type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('year') . '" value="' . $this->getYear()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Year')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '">' . $this->__('YYYY')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );
?>
```

To:

```
<?php
$disabled = '';
if($this->getFieldName('day') != ''){
    $disabled = 'disabled';
}
    $this->setDateInput('d',
        '<div class="dob-day">
             <input '.$disabled.' type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('day') . '" value="' . $this->getDay() . '" title="' . $this->__('Day') . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams() . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('day') . '">' . $this->__('DD') . '</label>
         </div>'
    );

    $this->setDateInput('m',
        '<div class="dob-month">
             <input '.$disabled.' type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('month') . '" value="' . $this->getMonth()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Month')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('month') . '">' . $this->__('MM')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );

    $this->setDateInput('y',
        '<div class="dob-year">
             <input '.$disabled.' type="text" id="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '" name="' . $this->getFieldName('year') . '" value="' . $this->getYear()  . '" title="' . $this->__('Year')  . '" class="input-text validate-custom" ' . $this->getFieldParams()  . ' />
             <label for="' . $this->getFieldId('year') . '">' . $this->__('YYYY')  . '</label>
         </div>'
    );
?>
```

It is simpliest way. But some users will able to find disabled tag and remove it from page. But 99,9% will not able to do this.

2. You may create observer for event `customer_save_before` and compare data from request and current customer data and update customer data or not before save.
   Add observer for `<customer_save_before>` event:

   ```
   <events>
       <customer_save_before>
           <observers>
               <your_observer>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                   <method>catchDobChange</method>
               </your_observer>
           </observers>
       </customer_save_before>
   </events>
   ```

In **Observer.php**:

```
public function catchDobChange($observer){
    if($observer->getCustomer()->getId() && $observer->getCustomer()->getData('dob') != $observer->getCustomer()->getOrigData('dob')){
        $observer->getCustomer()->setData('dob', $observer->getCustomer()->getOrigData('dob'));
    }
}
```